# reads a stream of (x, y) pairs from the command line and writes the modified pairs (x, f(y)) to a file

Tags: python, file, command-line, coordinates, argv

Here is the problem:

Read streams of (x, y) pairs from the command line.
Modify the datatrans1.py script such that it reads a stream of (x, y) pairs from the command line and writes the modified pairs (x, f(y)) to a file. The usage of the new script, here called datatrans1b.py, should be like this:

this is the input to the command line:
python datatrans1b.py tmp.out 1.1 3 2.6 8.3 7 -0.1675

resulting in an output file tmp.out:

- 1.1 1.20983e+01
- 2.6 9.78918e+00
- 7 0.00000e+00

Hint: Run through the sys.argv array in a for loop and use the range function
with appropriate start index and increment
Below is the datatrans1.py original script:

````
```
import sys, math

try:
   infilename = sys.argv[1]
   outfilename = sys.argv[2]
except:
   print("Usage:", sys.argv[0], "infile outfile")
   sys.exit(1)

ifile = open(infilename, 'r')  # open file for reading
ofile = open(outfilename, 'w')  # open file for writing


def myfunc(y):
   if y >= 0.0:
       return y ** 5 * math.exp(-y)
   else:
       return 0.0

```
````

read ifile line by line and write out transformed values:

````
```

for line in ifile:
   pair = line.split()
   x = float(pair[0])
   y = float(pair[1])
   fy = myfunc(y)  # transform y value
   ofile.write('hello' '%g  %12.5e\n' % (x, fy))
ifile.close()
ofile.close()

```
````

any clues on how to modify the above code to properly run the command line argument and generate the tmp.out file with the coordinate pairs would be really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve the problem:

```
import sys, math

try:
   outfilename = sys.argv[1]
except:
   print("Usage:", sys.argv[0], "outfile pairs")
   sys.exit(1)

ofile = open(outfilename, 'w')  # open file for writing

def myfunc(y):
   if y >= 0.0:
       return y ** 5 * math.exp(-y)
   else:
       return 0.0

# Loop through y values, using slices to start at position 3
# and get every second value
for i, y in enumerate(sys.argv[3::2]):

    # The corresponding x value is the one before the selected y value
    x = sys.argv[2:][i*2]

    # Call myfunc with y, converting y from string to float.
    fy = myfunc(float(y))

    # Write output using f-strings
    ofile.write(f'({x}, {fy})\n')
```